# Weird error defining variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is something wrong here,
either I'm stupid for not seeing something obvious, or way of defining variables changed this afternoon...

```
$(function() {
    console.log('something');
    var marquee = $('#marquee');
    var selected = $('#marquee ul li a img').first();
    var link = $('#marquee ul li a');
    var string = 'something else';
});
```

When I come to console, 'something' is not logged.
When I type 'marquee', jQuery object is returned, everything fine.
But, when I type 'selected', 'link', 'string', I get reference error, variable not defined.

I cleared cache, changed browser, removed 'var' before names, always the same.
Someone knows what is going on?

Comment: none of those variables are available outside of the `ready` function

Comment: Just for future use cash = cache

Comment: Yes, but why can I access marquee variable, and whay 'something' is not logging?

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem. You can't access `marquee` from console as it is written

Comment: When do you initiate the function?

Comment: The code seems to log "something" in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyp3V/), though notice what charlietfl and  ntgCleaner have commented.

Comment: I also tried something similar with jsbin.com... There, everything is as expeted... But on my computer, even when I change browser, I CAN access marquee variable, and something is not logged. Can there be problem with my entire computer?

Comment: Function is initiated when document is loaded, $(function(){}), I also tried $(document).ready

Comment: `$(function () {...})` is just a shortcut to `$(document).ready(...)`, hence the DOM ready event has already fired when you initiate the function, hence it is never executed.

Comment: I know it is the same, I tried it just in case. I never had both $(function(){}) and $(document).ready()

Comment: Reading this comment of yours tells else: "`**Function is initiated when document is loaded**, $(function(){}), I also tried $(document).ready`", hence my previous comment stands : ).

Comment: Yeah, I thought you don't know it is initiated when document is loaded. Let's just call it misunderstanding

Comment: I'm afraid I've to vote to close this question, if you can't provide a reproduceable example. Also the conflict between the nature of console (logs globals only outside of code execution) and a successful log of `marquee` makes me think there's something else in your code you haven't shown. Can you at least provide a link to the page?

Comment: No need to bother yourself, Jacques Marais gave me the answer. But, since I don't know where the problem was, I will delete question myself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## The problem

The problem is that the code is never executed. You think that the marquee variable is created, but it's not, because in the console an inputted value like `marquee` will print an element with an id set to the inputted value. So if you type `my_div` into the console and you do not set a my_div variable, it will return an element with the id of "my_div". (You can test it yourself if you don't believe me). So that means that the `marquee` variable is never set.

## The solution

One of the following solutions may or may not work.

### Solution 1

Put the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ });` rather than inside `$(function(){ });`.

Note: (This could maybe just be a bug on the jQuery version that your are using.

### Solution 2

Add your script under all your html in your `body` tag and not to the `head` tag.

Comment: Yes, now I get it, code was never execudet. I didn't know about typeing element id in console, so I was sure that code was execudet. So, now I recreated everything, not sure where the problem was, but now it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce any of your problems. I put your javascript into a jsfiddle and it does precisely what I would expect: logs "something" to the console, and I can't access any of the out-of-scope variables.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMHL3/

```
$(function() {
    console.log('something');
    var marquee = $('#marquee');
    var selected = $('#marquee ul li a img').first();
    var link = $('#marquee ul li a');
    var string = 'something else';
});
```

Comment: I also tried something similar with jsbin.com... There, everything is as expeted... But on my computer, even when I change browser, I CAN access marquee variable, and something is not logged. Can there be problem with my entire computer?

Comment: What is your HTML? Do you have any other code you're not showing us? How are you running it? A "problem with your entire computer" seems like an unlikely cause. Try adding more information/context about what you're doing until you can produce some demonstration of the problem that others can reproduce.

Comment: I know it is unlikely, but I have no other idea. My selector is good, because when I run $('#marquee ul li a'); in console, jquery object is returned. Other code is just jquery and modernizr.

Comment: Then try stripping your problem down to the barebones and adding things back til the problem returns. Try making a minimal html page with a reference to jquery, and a script tag with that code and see if you still get the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Are you testing this on a running web server? Or are you just loading the file locally from a path @user3829754?